# Containable Nested models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, containable

I have a few nested models which I'm trying to load using `Containable` behaviour in CakePHP.
Most of it works fine.

However, 1 model that has a `hasMany` relation only returns 1 object:

```
$article = $this->News->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array('News.id'=>$id),
    'contain' =>  array(
        'Newslayout', 
        'Newspicture'=> array(
            'NewspicturesProduct' => array(
                'Product' => array(
                    'Brand',
                    'Category'
                )
        )))
    ));
```

The object only being loaded once is the relation `Newspicture hasMany NewspicturesProduct`
When I log the queries, I get the following:

```
SELECT `NewspicturesProduct`.`id`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`x`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`y`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`product_id`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`newspicture_id`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`w`, `NewspicturesProduct`.`h` FROM `edclondon`.`newspictures_products` AS `NewspicturesProduct` WHERE `NewspicturesProduct`.`newspicture_id` = 3
```

Which gives me 3 results in `phpMyAdmin`. But only 1 in CakePHP's debug:

```
'Newspicture' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'news_id' => '2',
            'newspicture_file_path' => '5022443f-ddf8-4115-ae57-618e9d60b047.jpg',
            'newspicture_file_size' => '1232546',
            'order' => null,
            'NewspicturesProduct' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'x' => '0.180664',
                'y' => '0.295312',
                'product_id' => '3',
                'newspicture_id' => '3',
                'w' => '0.286133',
                'h' => '0.478125',
                'Product' => array(
                    'id' => '3',
                    //....
                    'Brand' => array(
                        'id' => '6',
                        //...
                    ),
                    'Category' => array(
                        'id' => '6',
                        //....
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

When retrieving the `Newspictures` object rather then retrieving the `News` object, I do get all 3 `NewspicturesProduct` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the code corresponding the query you showed should be:

```
$article = $this->News->find('first',array(
'contain' =>  array(
    'Newslayout', 
    'Newspicture'=> array(
        'NewspicturesProduct' => array(
            'conditions'=>array('NewspicturesProduct.newspicture_id'=>'3')
            'Product' => array(
                'Brand',
                'Category'
            )
    )))
));
```

and not the one you gave...

Comment: But how can you know `Newspicture.id` in the same query where you're retrieving the `News.id`

Answer (score -1):

It seems you need 3 records from `NewspicturesProduct`. If that then you can try:

```
$article = $this->News->find('first',array(
'contain' =>  array(
    'Newslayout', 
    'Newspicture'=> array(
        'NewspicturesProduct' => array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                             'limit'=> 3
                         ),
            'Product' => array(
                'Brand',
                'Category'
            )
    )))
));
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however I have 3 corresponding records but the problem is I only get 1. Not so much that I don't want more then 3, rather I want more then 1